# Unable to read a continuous data stream from a node child process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, command-line-interface, shopify, child-process

## First things first. The goal I want to achieve:

I have two processes:

- the first one is webpack that just watches for file changes and pushes the bundled files into the `dist/` directory
- the second process (Shopify CLI) watches for any file changes in the `dist/` directory and pushes them to a remote destination

My goal is to have only one command (like `npm run start`) which simultaneously runs both processes without printing anything to the terminal so I can print custom messages. And that's where the problem starts:

## How can I continuously read child process terminal output?

Printing custom messages for webpack events at the right time is pretty easy, since webpack has a Node API for that. But the Shopify CLI only gives me the ability to capture their output and process it.

Normally, the Shopify CLI prints something like "Finished Upload" as soon as the changed file has been pushed. It works perfectly fine for the first time but after that, nothing is printed to the terminal anymore.

Here is a minimal representation of what my current setup looks like:

```js
const spawn = require('spawn');

const childProcess = spawn('shopify', ['theme', 'serve'], {
  stdio: 'pipe',
});

childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  // Just to make sure there are no errors
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I think we can all benefit if you explain what you're actually trying to solve, what's your original problem.

Comment: @FabioFilippi It's mostly about ease of development (process-wise). I could just have two terminals open at the same time with both processes running natively and it would just work fine. But that's something I'd like to prevent (if possible). Does that help? :?

Comment: So if I understand correctlty you want to have npm run dev (or similar) and shopify theme watch running on the same window? Are you on windows or linux or mac?

Comment: @FabioFilippi yeah, but that's only one part of the challenge (which I have already solved). The other part is about capturing the terminal output. I am on Mac but the solution has to work for Windows aswell